# ARM Thumb mode relocation

Tags: assembly, arm, gnu, cortex-m, thumb

Cortex M3-Vector table looks like this using gnu-as

```
.long STACK_START
.long _reset
.long 0x0 //Reserved   
.long _hard_fault
...
```

The problem is symbol addresses must have the bottom bit set because they point to thumb code. Gnu-as translates `_reset` into a relocation for the linker to fit, and the linker doesn't add the bottom bit, also I can't do something like `(_reset | 1)` because of the same.

I could set _reset to a fixed location and "hardcode" the vector, but I'm tyring to avoid that.

Maybe there is a way to prevent gnu-as to translate `_reset` into a relocation, so I can use it a constant value.

The `_reset:` label is allowed to be in the same compilation unit as the vector table.

**Example to let this more clear:**

```
 .long  STACK_START
 .long _reset
 ...

 _reset:
     b _reset
```

**Is assembled as:**

```
00000000 <vectors>:
   0:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
   4:   000000c0    andeq   r0, r0, r0, asr #1
    ...

000000c0 <_reset>:
  c0:   e7fe        b.n c0 <_reset>
  c2:   bf00        nop
```

I want the `000000c0` to be assembled as `000000c1`

Comment: You'll have to add `.thumb_func` before the `_reset`-label.

Comment: Note: it doesnt have to be immediately before the label, it is a flag that indicates the next label is a thumb function label and the address of is orred with 1.  you could have .thumb_func; .globl something; something: for example  but, yes, the tool will solve this problem of generating thumb function addresses for you.

Comment: Not in any way implying that EOF meant immediately before the label.   Just generally saying that you can be a bit loose with the .thumb_func as to its exact location to add to his comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it working.

Comment: By the way, why did a get a -1, formatting? lack of clarity?

Comment: @Felipe: Not my DV, but I'd wager it's for lack of research.